# How do I pass a Python variable to Bash Shell over SSH connection?

Tags: python, bash, variables, ssh

I try to check file existence on a remote server. Everything works fine for me, except that I want to pass the file path as a variable.

Here is what I do
 `_,stdout,_=ssh.exec_command("[ -f d:/tryssh/1.txt ] && echo OK")`

and I need this `d:/tryssh/1.txt` to be a variable that I specify in the python script to be used later in the bash, something like this

```
          `_,stdout,_=ssh.exec_command("[ -f $filePath ] && echo OK")`
```

Answer (score 1):

As your command is a string, use it as a string:

```
file_path = "d:/tryssh/1.txt"
command = "[ -f %s ] && echo OK" % file_path
_,stdout,_=ssh.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Simply because `%s` is not identified in the bash syntax, only in python syntax. But thanks anyway